# Looping through specific array elements

Tags: php

I have a table and each row contains, among other things, 5 columns which may or may not contain an image file name. Let's say I've retrieved that row and put it into an assoc array. I want to loop through and echo those image file names (cols may or may not all be populated) into html tags, but only if that column has an image file name in it. Is there a better way to do it than this?

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
if($item_array['image_' . {$i}]{
echo "<li><img src=\"images/work-items/$item_array['image_' . {$i} . '.jpg'\"/></li>"
}
```

Comment: Your if parenthesis is unclosed. No semicolon either. Guess this is pseudocode then, so my points are moot.

Comment: try `if( ! empty($item_array['image_' . {$i}])) {`

Comment: @Asad: or the for parenthesis is unclosed. :)

Comment: Your solution is ok (except details), what would you want that'd be better ?

Comment: @JvdBerg that is actually a different issue, because I was talking about the missing `)`

Comment: @Asad: ahh .. ok. Braces and parenthesis .. difficult for a dutchman

Comment: oops sorry, yes this is rushed sudo code.

Comment: @theredled: I should have been clearer. I guess I feel like having to specify how many times to iterate the loop isn't good enough. Maybe I'm just being anal.

Comment: Make it simple. If the column count isn't likely to change, and if you don't write it 43 time in your code, then hardcode it, no pb.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax was all over the place:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
    if(isset($item_array['image_' . $i])){
        echo '<li><img src="images/work-items/'. $item_array['image_' . $i] . '.jpg"/></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the "isset" make any difference? I thought a populated array element would equate to TRUE anyway?

Comment: If a particular array index doesn't exist and you attempt to output it, PHP will spit out a warning notice.

Comment: I guessed it existed all the time. Anyway, if you want to check this case, better use `!empty()`

Comment: But I wouldn't try to output an empty array index, as the condition is that it will only be echo'd if TRUE / populated... ?

Comment: If you use if($item_array['image_' . $i]), it'll throw a warning if "'image_' . $i" doesn't exist as an array index.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. However the array index "image_" . $i will always exist, as it's referring to a set number of columns in table, of which there will always be 5. They may just not all be populated.